# Why detailed error message is not passed to HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am using the default Web Api controller that is auto generated. I am testing the validation and error handling in the client side. But somehow I have realised that the detail error message is not passed to client. Either if I throw HttpResponseException or returning IHttpActionResult in both cases the client is seeing only "Bad Request" but not the detailed message. Can anyone explain what is going wrong please?

```
     public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        if (id <= 0)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Id should be greater than zero.", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"),
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound

            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(response) // Either this way
        }

        var itemToDelete = (from i in Values
                            where i.Id == id
                            select i).SingleOrDefault();

        if (itemToDelete == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(string.Format("Unable to find a value for the Id {0}", id)); // Or This way
        }

        Values.Remove(itemToDelete);
        return Ok();
    }
```

**client code is as:**

```
 private async static Task DeleteValue(int id)
    {

        var url = "http://localhost:13628/api/Values/" + id;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.DeleteAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                await ReadValues();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.ReasonPhrase);
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

None of the above works??

Thx

Comment: Did you get a message in `response`?

Comment: *In general*, exposing the inner workings of your web server serve no useful purpose to benign users but may expose flaws to malicious users. As such, *defaults* tend to be to hide detailed information.

Answer (score 24):

In your client side change `Console.WriteLine(response.ReasonPhrase);`

to `Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);`

and it will give the detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code into Web API delete action. Use `HttpResponseMessage` as return tpye for api instead of `IHttpActionResult`

```
        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("{id:int:min(1)}")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteAsync(int id)
        {
            if(id < 0 )
            {
                return await Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Id should be greater than zero."));
            }
            try
            {
                var itemToDelete = (from i in Values
                                    where i.Id == id
                                    select i).SingleOrDefault();

                if (itemToDelete == null)
                {
                    return await Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
                                        string.Format("Unable to find a value for the Id {0}", id))); 
                }

                Values.Remove(itemToDelete);
                return await Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Something went wrong."); // Default message if exception occured
            }
        }
```

And client Side:

```
        private async static Task DeleteValue(int id)
        {

            var url = "http://localhost:13628/api/Values/" + id;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.DeleteAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await ReadValues();
                }
                else
                {
                    var errorMessage = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    // Here Newtonsoft.Json Package is used to deserialize response content 
                    Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                }
            }
        }
```

Above code is working at my side.